# What is the difference in nuance between いっさい and いっこう?

Tags: grammar

I see いっさい + neg. as meaning "not even a little bit". For example, in this snippet:

> 火山はただの火山としてその他の説明をいっさいしないのです。

from [here](https://toyokeizai.net/articles/-/85403?page=3).

I translate that as "Not even a little bit does he make any explanation other than the simplest possible explanation of the volcano representing just a volcano."

I have seen いっこうに being used to express a similar connotation of 'not even a little bit'; for example [this sentence](https://jisho.org/sentences/518669aed5dda7e98100a93e).

Is there a difference in nuance between the two or can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that 一向に～ない has a nuance like "Someone doesn't do(or Something doesn't happen), even though time passed."
For example, we say "彼を東京駅で待っているけど、一向に来ません。"